# How can I make this Scala code even more short?

Tags: scala, matrix, functional-programming, spiral

The input is a spiral matrix and the output should be a string of the numbers in increasing order evidently.

```
 def spiral(x: List[List[Int]]): Unit = x match {
      case List() =>
        println()
      case head :: tail =>
        print(head.mkString(" ") + " ")
        spiral(tail.transpose.reverse)
    }

val matrix = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
spiral(matrix)
```

I want to have the shortest solution possible in Scala, though I struggle to write it in a shorter way than the one above.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also `if(x==Nil)println()else{print(x.head.mkString(" ")+" ");spiral(x.tail.transpose.reverse)}` is shorter. but as I said above, it's just codegolfing?

Comment: Indeed it is. Sorry for posting off-topic, I just started to find my way on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Not really shorter, but I tried

```
def sp(xs: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] =
   xs.collectFirst { case x => x:::sp(xs.tail.transpose.reverse) }.getOrElse(Nil)
```

Comment: Thanks anyways it is actually shorter. I tried it from a completely different perspective.